# Getting ID of detail-page instance that is currently open

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How to handle `PushNotifications` in my Ionic3 / AngularJS mobile app are shown to my users while the app is open? I can identify page which the user is currently on and I can do that by:

```
if ( (this.navCtrl.getActive().component === Page1) ){
    // user is currently on Page1
    // handle push notification
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not enough. `Page1` is a detail page, which shows details of an item. Let's say there are 3 items: Banana (`id: 1`), Apple (`id: 2`) and Orange (`id: 3`).

I need to know, whether the user is currently looking at Page1 for item1, item2 or item3. I want to do something like this:

```
if ( (this.navCtrl.getActive().component === Page1 && data.itemID === "page1-itemId") ){
    // data.itemID is the ID i get from the push notification
    // "page1-itemId" is what I desire to get somehow
}
```

How could I find out about `page1-itemId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, anybody will struggle with the same thing: I decided to use Events for this purpose.

Whenever Page1 is opened, I publish an Event like this:

***Page1.ts***

```
constructor(...
     public events: Events
) {
     // read NavParams
     this.itemId= this.navParams.get('itemId');

     // publish event with current itemId
     this.events.publish("Page1:opened",this.itemId);
}
```

Then I listen to this event in my ***app.component.ts***

```
// Listen to Opening of Confirm-Page
this.events.subscribe('Page1:opened', itemId=> {
   this.page1ItemId= itemId;
});
```

... and use `this.page1ItemId` in combination with `this.nav.getActive().component === Page1` to handle the notification the way I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do something like from component which navigates to `Detail` component.

```
this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, {
  id: "1",
});
```

and then in `Detail` page read that id `param` like this. Don't forget to import and inject `Navparams` in constructor

```
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
  let id = navParams.get('id');
}
```

source [Ionic NavController docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

Comment: Thanks, Rajkishor. However, this isn't what I asked for.

Comment: `Page1 is a detail page, which shows details of an item`. Actually I assumed, there is a page with list of items and when you select an item then you need to show detail of an item. Can you please provide more info on that?

Comment: Please re-read my initial post. As I said, I need to know, whether the user is currently looking at Page1 for item1, item2 or item3 to handle the incoming push notification depending on which item the user is currently looking at.